# How can I return a String Vector?

Tags: string, rust

How can I return a String Vector in Rust? I tried:

```
fn test_vec() -> Vec<&str> {
    vec!("foo", "bar")
}
```

The compiler says something about lifetimes, but I'm not sure my problem is really about lifetimes:

```
src/main.rs:9:22: 9:26 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
```

I'm a bit lost, I think I misunderstood (or forgot to learn) something.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20test_vec()%20-%3E%20Vec%3C%26%27static%20str%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20vec!%5B%22foo%22%2C%20%22bar%22%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20test_vec())%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `&str` is not a `String`. It is a "string slice", meaning a kind of pointer into a `String` or something equivalent that is stored somewhere else. In your case you are using string literals (using quotes gives you string literals). String literals are of the type `&'static str`, because they are stored in the same place where the compiled code is stored and thus are available for the `'static` lifetime, which means for (at least) the entire runtime of your program.

So the easy fix is to have your method return that specific type: `&'static str`.

---

The compiler cannot infer a lifetime for the returned reference, because your function does not take any arguments of reference type. The only way the compiler will infer a lifetime in a function's signature, is by assuming that if you are returning a reference, it needs to live shorter than the argument it's referring to. There's more information in [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision)